# Ignore folders in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

How can I tell [**`PhpStorm`**](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) to *ignore folders* in a project?

***e.g:*** I would like to ignore these folders for good without deleting them.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What's wrong with:

> Right click the directory -> Mark Directory As -> Excluded

Comment: Definitely nothing wrong with it! Well I can't screen through the folders but I don't need to anyway. Thanks @markus

Comment: Thank you. There is a symlink in my project that was resolving to the directory and throwing some things off. Excluding it got rid of a lot of annoying notifications from PHPStorm.

Comment: It would be nice to still see the contents of the directory, just not have it get indexed with the rest... if that exists, I'd be interested in knowing how.